# Obter dados de uma coluna no banco para uma váriavel

Tags: c#, sql

Em uma parte do meu código tenho o tratamento de uma exceção que usa essa mensagem.

```
 //Grava log com sucesso da importação
fundo.registerLog(Resources.MensagemSucessoImportacao);
```

A mensagem fica dentro de um arquivo *Resource*, porém ela é concatenada.

```
Arquivo {0} importado com sucesso.
```

O {0} é onde ficará minha coluna da tabela do banco.

Minha classe não tem uma variável que pegue essa coluna.

Detalhe: Essa coluna vem de uma procedure:

```
 Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();            
 DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("PR_LOG");

 //Adds other parameters
 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "P_DESCRICAO_LOG", DbType.String, logDescription);
```

A estrutura acima fica em uma outra classe do projeto, dentro de um metódo.

Como faço pra pegar essa coluna, jogar numa variável e colocar essa variável após `Resources.MensagemSucessoImportacao`?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi, falta apenas usar [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
fundo.registerLog(String.Format(Resources.MensagemSucessoImportacao, logDescription));
```

Comment: logDescription não existe no contexto de onde está a mensagem, como eu disse acima essa parte está em outra classe do projeto.

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: @ThamiresCunha Qual seria o nome da variável que existe neste contexto, então? Pode por favor atualizar sua pergunta?

Comment: Como tbm citado acima, nesse contexto não tem uma variável que pegue essa coluna, eu teria que criar.. minha dúvida é como pegar essa possivel variavel que eu vou criar e conectar com essa coluna..

Comment: @ThamiresCunha Sem mais detalhes fica impossível responder.

Comment: Morrison Acho que não me expressei bem.. Gostaria de pegar o nome do arquivo e concatenar com a mensagem. Não tem colunas na tabela do banco que guardem o nome do arquivo.

Comment: gostaria que a mensagem ficasse ex.: Arquivo TESTE.txt importado com sucesso